# How do you change multiple column names in a Julia (version 0.3) DataFrame?

Tags: julia

For example say you create a Julia DataFrame like so with 20 columns:

```
y=convert(DataFrame, randn(10,20))
```

How do you convert the column names `(:x1 ... :x20)` to something else, like `(:col1, ..., :col20)` for example, all at once?

Comment: I've tried the below for v0.6 with no success, can we reopen?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You might find the `names!` function more concise:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(x1 = 1:2, x2 = 2:3, x3 = 3:4)
2x3 DataFrame
|-------|----|----|----|
| Row # | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| 1     | 1  | 2  | 3  |
| 2     | 2  | 3  | 4  |

julia> names!(df, [symbol("col$i") for i in 1:3])
Index([:col2=>2,:col1=>1,:col3=>3],[:col1,:col2,:col3])

julia> df
2x3 DataFrame
|-------|------|------|------|
| Row # | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| 1     | 1    | 2    | 3    |
| 2     | 2    | 3    | 4    |
```

Comment: I would like this more concise solution, but it does not seem to work with new Julia versions (e.g. 0.6.2). Solution with `rename!` still works.

Comment: In julia v0.6.2, change `symbol` to `Symbol`

Comment: names!() is deprecated now, you can use the above if you replace `names!` by `rename!`

Answer (score 8):

One way to do this is with the `rename!` function. The method of the rename function takes a `DataFrame` as input though only allows you to change a single column name at a time (as of the development version 0.3 branch on 1/4/2014). Looking into the code of `Index.jl` in the DataFrames repository lead me to this solution which works for me:

```
rename!(y.colindex, [(symbol("x$i")=>symbol("col$i")) for i in 1:20])
```

`y.colindex` returns the index for the dataframe `y`, and the next argument creates a dictionary mapping the old column symbols to the new column symbols. I imagine that by the time someone else needs this, there will be a nicer way to do this, but I just spent a few hours figuring this out in the development version 0.3 of Julia, so I thought i would share!

Answer (score 5):

As an update to the answer of @JohnMylesWhite, the `names!` function has been deprecated in `DataFrames v 0.20.2`. The latest way of going about this is by using the `rename!` function:

```
import DataFrames
DF = DataFrames

df = DF.DataFrame(x1 = 1:2, x2 = 2:3, x3 = 3:4)
println(df)
DF.rename!(df, [Symbol("Col$i") for i in 1:size(df,2)])
println(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

**v1.1.0**

One can directly change the column names by

```
names!(df, colNames_as_Symbols)
```

To rename the columns with a vector of strings, this can be done via

```
names!(df, Symbol.(colNames_as_strings) )
```

Comment: Just trying this, I think this should be name*s*!

Comment: @Crown42: yep! That leaves me asking why didn't I copy and paste?

Answer (score 3):

```
# import Pkg; Pkg.add("DataFrames")
using DataFrames
```

The question has been answered, but for the additional clarity, sometimes you just want to specify the names without using loops (i.e. over-engineering):

```
rename!(df, [:Date, :feature_1, :feature_2 ], makeunique=true)
```

Example output:

```
141 rows × 3 columns

Date    feature_1   feature_2
Date    Float64?    Float64?
1   2020-08-03  44.3    missing
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**:
For Julia 0.4, as described by John Myles White, all the names can be changed with:

```
names!(df::AbstractDataFrame, vals)
```

where `vals` is a Vector{Symbol} the same length as
  the number of columns in `df`.

Specific names can be changed with:

```
rename!(df::AbstractDataFrame, from::Symbol, to::Symbol)
rename!(df::AbstractDataFrame, d::Associative)
rename!(f::Function, df::AbstractDataFrame)
```

where `d` is an Associative type that maps the original name to a new name
and `f` is a function that has the old column name (a symbol) as input
  and new column name (a symbol) as output.

This is documented in the code at https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/blob/7e2f48ad9f31185d279fdd81d6413a79b7e42e87/src/abstractdataframe/abstractdataframe.jl

Answer (score 1):

This is the short and simple answer for Julia 1.1.1:

```
names!(df, [Symbol("Col$i") for i in 1:size(df,2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the rename function with an array containing the new names:

```
Vector_with_names = ["col1","col2","col3"]
rename!(df,Vector_with_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using John's dataframe, i had to use `colnames!` instead of `names!`

```
df = DataFrame(x1 = 1:2, x2 = 2:3, x3 = 3:4)
colnames!(df, ["col$i" for i in 1:3])
```

My  version of Julia is `0.2.1`

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is depreciated (Julia v1.1.0)